# OnLoad javascript AJAX Call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create an onload event where an AJAX function is called and passed a value. I can't put it on body because I have both my header and footer cut in sections via PHP. Apparently I can't put this on a div and

```
    $(#midContainer).ready(function(){
        Change('value1');
    });
```

This doesnt seem to work and I am not sure why. I got an
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: You are missing quotes around the element ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
$(#midContainer).ready(function(){
    Change('value1');
});
```

with

```
$("#midContainer").ready(function(){
    Change('value1');
});
```

You are missing quotes around your DIV's Id

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with `document.ready` ?

```
$(function(){
   Change('value1');
})
```